# jQuery add field on click error inside simpleTabs jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, tabs

I have this code

jQuery its an add new input field

```
var scntDiv = $('.q3_field');
var i = $('.q3_field p').size() + 1;

$('.add_field_q3').live('click', function() {
        $('<p><span class="added'+i+'"><input type="text" name="inputq3['+i+'][q3]" class="edit-text" placeholder="http://www.domain.com" /></span> <img src="hw_img/trash.png" id="remScnt" /></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
        if( i > 1 ) {
                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                i--;
        }
        return false;
});
```

HTML - where it will be added

```
<div class="simpleTabs"><a href="#questions">Questions</a></div>
<div id="questions">
    <li class="q3_field">
        List five (URL) links you would like to be displaced/removed in search engine results related to your name/keywords. These can be named below or marked on a print out of a relevant Google search. <br />

        <img src="hw_img/plus.png" class="add_field_q3" /> 
        <input type="text" name="inputq3[0][q3]" class="edit-text" placeholder="http://www.domain.com" /> <br />
    </li>
</div>
```

I am using simpleTabs jQuery where i put my simple hard code of adding input fields.
But when i click it to add, it double the field.
please see the image below.
[image]

I try that outside of the simpleTabs jQuery, it doesn't double the field when i click the add button.
Yes when im not going to use the simpleTabs.

Is there any conflict from from simTabls that i download from google? That is why it double the field when i click add button?

the codes of tab which i put it on the footer.

```
<script src="hw_js/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#tab-container').easytabs();
});
</script>
```

UPDATE
the weird part is that when i check it on fireBug
it also double the span and id which is the same 1 and 1 2 and 2 please check the image below.
[image]

Comment: Just in case if you're using a low version of jquery `.live()` is deprecated in jquery v1.7++ so it should be `.on('click',function(){})`

Comment: hi i try that one `.on('click',function(){})` but its still not working but when without simpleTabs it was working fine...

Comment: can you reproduce this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? or show me a sample site.

Comment: okie wait i will try that on jsfiddle

Comment: hi this is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanentila/d4zTm/2/, however i dont find any error and actually it was working fine on jsfiddle...

Comment: it was working fine now. i just put it on the footer and it was working fine now. thank you verymuch stackoverflow teams...